# Using Crippled as a verb

Tags: verbs, nouns

Is it right to use the word *crippled* as a verb with the sense *disabled/unable to do things?*

An example sentence:

> I am crippled to complete my tasks as I didn't receive the
>   credentials.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "am crippled to" on the internet, then looking to see how many of the first 100 say returns are followed by an infinitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use *crippled* as a verb.

Per [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cripple):

> **Cripple** *transitive verb*
>
> **To deprive of the use of a limb and especially a leg**: *the accident left him crippled*
>
> **To deprive of capability for service or of strength, efficiency, or
> wholeness** : *an economy crippled by inflation*

Also, from [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cripple):

> *This measure crippled our efforts*
>
> *The accident has crippled her for life*

However, I don't think **crippled to** fits as-is in your sentence. You're better off using words like unable, or [hindered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hinder).

> I am unable to complete my tasks as I didn't receive the credentials.

Comment: _The efforts can be crippled_ and _the person can be crippled_ but someone is not crippled to do something. So yes you can use it as a verb, but not in the sentence proposed by OP

Answer (score 4):

That would not be idiomatic English.

*Efforts can be crippled* and *a person can be crippled* but someone is not **crippled to** do something unless that person is disabled (too crippled to perform his tasks because of lack of fingers).

I suggest

> I am blocked from completing my tasks

or to use your word

> > My ability to complete my tasks is crippled by the lack of credentials

Answer (score 0):

I crippled, he crippled, they crippled. I cripple, he cripples, they cripple.

> His lack of credentials crippled his efforts

Comment: I already mentioned that _Efforts can be crippled_